# android - Autobahn Websocket Connection

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

I am working on Autobahn Web socket communication. There is a carousel view in my application, and there are four images. When users click on of the images, then connects to server with websocket and send message. But the problem is that when I select the images, it connects to server correctly, but client(android device) connects to the websocket every single time when the message is sent.
Here is my code..

```
if (pos == 0) {
    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_0);
    product_photo.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            String id = "Product0";
            Log.d(TAG, "Current product is : " + id);
            A.sendMessage(id);  
        }
    });
}
```

Websocket.class

```
public class WebSocket_Connector extends Activity{

    private static final String TAG = "ECHOCLIENT";
    private static final String TAG1 = "My app";
    public final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();
    private String tmpString = "";

    public void connect(final String wsuri) {

          Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to: " + wsuri); 

          try {
             mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onOpen() {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri ); 
                   Log.d(TAG, "Connection successful!\n");
                   mConnection.sendTextMessage(tmpString); 
                   tmpString = "";
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Got echo: " + payload);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Connection closed.");
                }
             });
          } catch (WebSocketException e) {

             Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
          }
       }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mConnection.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG1, "Messeage is sent : " + message);
            mConnection.sendTextMessage(message); 

        }
        else {
            tmpString = message;
            connect("ws://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx");
        }
    }   
}
```

It doens't go to 'if (mConnection.isConnected())' here..always goes to else.

Comment: What Autobahn Websocket server are you using? The echo server?

Comment: Is "A" the object of WebSocket_Connector class?